# BeautifulSoup - Find elements Directly below and above heading with specific string

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

How can I scrape the following structure to only get h3,h4 class above h5 string ="Prem League" and div class="fixres_item" directly below h5 string "Prem League".

I would want the text from h3, h4 and inside the div I need the text from a span , inside a span

So when h5 class string is Prem League I want the h4 and h3 directly above, and also I need to geyt various elements our of the fixres_item directly below h5 class string = Prem League

```
<div class="fixres__body" data-url="" data-view="fixture-update" data-controller="fixture-update" data-fn="live-refresh" data-sport="football" data-lite="true" id="widgetLite-6">
    <h3 class="fixres__header1">November 2018</h3>          
    <h4 class="fixres__header2">Saturday 24th November</h4>             
    <h5 class="fixres__header3">Prem League</h5>
    <div class="fixres__item">stuff in here</div>

    <h4 class="fixres__header2">Wednesday 28th November</h4>
    <h5 class="fixres__header3">UEFA Champ League</h5>
    <div class="fixres__item">stuff in here</div>

    <h3 class="fixres__header1">December 2018</h3>          
    <h4 class="fixres__header2">Sunday 2nd December</h4>                
    <h5 class="fixres__header3">Prem League</h5>
    <div class="fixres__item">stuff in here</div>
```

This is the code I have so far, but this includes data from divs below h5 string "EUFA Champ League" - which I do not want. I only want data from the divs that are below h5 heading "Prem League". For example I do not want PSG in the output because it comes from the div below h5 heading "EUFA Champ League"

My Code -

```
def squad_fixtures():
    team_table = ['https://someurl.com/liverpool-fixtures']

    for i in team_table:

#        team_fixture_urls = [i.replace('-squad', '-fixtures') for i in team_table]

        squad_r = requests.get(i)
        premier_squad_soup = BeautifulSoup(squad_r.text, 'html.parser')
#        print(premier_squad_soup)
        premier_fix_body = premier_squad_soup.find('div', {'class': 'fixres__body'})
#        print(premier_fix_body)

        premier_fix_divs = premier_fix_body.find_all('div', {'class': 'fixres__item'})

    for i in premier_fix_divs:  
        team_home = i.find_all('span', {'class': 'matches__item-col matches__participant matches__participant--side1'})
        for i in team_home:
            team_home_names = i.find('span', {'class': 'swap-text--bp30'})['title']
            team_home_namesall.append(team_home_names)
    print(team_home_namesall)
```

The output
    ['Watford', 'PSG', 'Liverpool', 'Burnley', "B'mouth", 'Liverpool', 'Liverpool', 'Wolves', 'Liverpool', 'Liverpool', 'Man City', 'Brighton', 'Liverpool', 'Liverpool', 'West Ham', 'Liverpool', 'Man Utd', 'Liverpool', 'Everton', 'Liverpool', 'Fulham', 'Liverpool', "So'ton", 'Liverpool', 'Cardiff', 'Liverpool', 'Newcastle', 'Liverpool']

Comment: show your python code

Comment: @ewwink - updated and added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your challenge is restricting the scraping to just the `Premier League` `<h5>` and its associated content.

> Note: Your question states the `string` of the `h5` should be `Prem League`, but it in fact appears to be `Premier League` when I look at the response.

This HTML appears to be pretty flat and undifferentiated in structure, so it looks like the best thing is to walk through the siblings previous and next from the h5, which is itself fairly easy to locate:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
import requests

prem_league_regex = re.compile(r"Premier League")


def squad_fixtures():
    team_table = ['https://www.skysports.com/liverpool-fixtures']

    for i in team_table:
        squad_r = requests.get(i)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(squad_r.text, 'html.parser')
        body = soup.find('div', {'class': 'fixres__body'})
        h5s = body.find_all('h5', {'class': 'fixres__header3'}, text=prem_league_regex)
        for h5 in h5s:
            prev_tag = find_previous(h5)
            if prev_tag.name == 'h4':
                print(prev_tag.text)
            prev_tag = find_previous(prev_tag)
            if prev_tag.name == 'h3':
                print(prev_tag.text)
            fixres_item_div = find_next(h5)
            """
                get the things you need from fixres__item now that you have it...
            """



def find_previous(tag):
    prev_tag = tag.previous_sibling
    while(not isinstance(prev_tag, Tag)):
        prev_tag = prev_tag.previous_sibling
    return prev_tag

def find_next(tag):
    next_tag = tag.next_sibling
    while(not isinstance(next_tag, Tag)):
        next_tag = next_tag.next_sibling
    return next_tag
```

Comment: Yes the h5 string is Premier League. I will give that a try thanks

Comment: fixres_item_div seems to only pull one div, any idea why that would be?

Comment: Since you have more than one h5 tag you're trying to find (I misunderstood that), use `find_all` instead of `find`, and iterate on the results.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome!  Don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you.